# Calling function using base class pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hey I am just trying to figure out the concept of using base class pointer to call methods of derived class, but then I came across this problem.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    int a;
public:
    A() {}
    A(int x) :a(x) {}
    void show() {
        cout<<"Hi this is base class ::\nvalue of a is "<<a<<endl;
    }
};

class B:public A {
    int b;
public:
    B() {}
    B(int x) : b(x) {}
    void show() {
        cout<<"Hi this is derived class::\n value of b is "<<b<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a(20), *a_ptr;
    B b(10), *b_ptr;
    a_ptr = &b;
    a.show();
    a_ptr->show();
    return 0;
}
```

`a.show()` outputs:

```
Hi this is base class ::
value of a is 20
```

as accepted but 
`a_ptr->show()` outputs garbage value

```
Hi this is base class ::
value of a is -1121246592
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening..

Comment: Not angry felt helpless after helped you, while getting down vote!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple you didn't initialize your base class data member when you are calling a derived class constructor so it is showing garbage value; since it will call base class default constructor.

If you change your base class default constructor as follows, you will get expected result.

```
 A():a(10) {}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because in order to have polymorphism you have to define `show()` as a virtual function, i.e. in `class A`:

```
virtual void show();
```

As this is not the case in your code the compiler will statically bind the call  `a_ptr->show();` to `class A` implementation of show which prints the member `a` which is not initialized by `class B` constructor.

Comment: The keyword virtual is used to mark these methods that their behavior can be overridden by the derived classes. Then the compiler will translate this a call to the base class pointer to go through the class vtable in order to resolve the right version of the function to call. You can find more info about it in [cpprefernece](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual).

Comment: The key word here is *polymorphism*.  Understand that concept first.  Then the keyword `virtual` will make more sense.

Comment: @Steephen there is no object slicing here

Comment: Thanks zmb for clarification